# AWS S3 LISTING is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to execute the following command using AWS CLI on an S3 bucket:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket name/folder_name --summarize --human-readable --recursive
```

I am trying to get the size of the folder, but given there are multiple levels and a huge number of files, it running for hours.

Is there an efficient way to quickly get the size at folder level on Amazon S3?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html):

> Amazon S3 inventory provides comma-separated values (CSV) or Apache optimized row columnar (ORC) output files that list your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

You would need to parse the file, but all information is provided.

It is only updated daily, so if you need something faster then you'd have to make the calls yourself.